How to find group pair duplicates in Excel (creating graph nodes)
I have a class of 40 students performing 5 group activities. Each group having 3-4 students per activity.  My goal using Excel is to find and minimize the number of instances where students have the same group members across activities.
After working with some randomization, an example of the initial student activity / group data is structured with 10 students in 3 groups across 3 activities.  The actual team numbers are completely arbitrary, so it does not matter if a student is in the same team number more than once.



index
student
activity 1 team
activity 2 team
activity 3 team




1
Freddy Mercury
1
2
2


2
Annie Lenox
2
2
3


3
Steven Tyler
3
2
1


4
Cyndi Lauper
1
2
3


5
Vince Neil
3
1
2


6
Tina Turner
3
3
3


7
Roger Daltrey
1
3
1


8
Lita Ford
2
3
1


9
Robert Plant
3
1
2


10
George Michael
1
1
1



Using a combination of INDEX, IF, IFERROR, SMALL, ROW, MIN, and COLUMN, I'm able to revisualize the teams in separate group views. This isn't very useful for my end goal, and I'd prefer to not do this for the final solution.  Yet, I am sharing it here in case it is easier for you to see what I'm trying to do.  I added color and bold for emphasis.  
Using Activity 1 as the baseline, the bold text shows Freddie Mercury and Cyndi Lauper being in the same team again in Activity 2, and Roger Daltrey and George Michael in the same team again in Activity 3.
Using Power Query, I was able to restructure the data into long form, such as:



index
student
activity#_team#




1
Freddy Mercury
A1_1


1
Freddy Mercury
A2_1


1
Freddy Mercury
A3_2


2
Annie Lennox
A1_1


2
Annie Lennox
A2_2


2
Annie Lennox
A3_3


3
Steven Tyler
A1_1


3
Steven Tyler
A2_2


3
Steven Tyler
A3_1



This is where I am stuck.  I thought of using COUNTIFS with names and Activity#_Team#, but because the Activity#_Team# assignment is arbitrary and repeats, it doesn't seem a viable solution.  E.g., Freddy and Cyndi are on the same team in Activities 1 and 2, but they have different team numbers each time.
At the moment, I am trying to move toward a graph node style list, after which I could concatenate the student name pairs and flag the duplicates.



student A
student B
activity#_team#
concat_pair
duplicate




Freddy Mercury
Annie Lennox
A1_1
Freddy Mercury - Annie Lennox
FALSE



However, I haven't figured out yet how to restructure the data into the node list.  I'm open to any solutions, but I'd prefer a non-VBA approach.
Ideally, solution options are scalable and dynamic, so I could implement the same solution across multiple classes that have different numbers of students and teams.
Thanks in advance!
